# Opencart 2.3 url doesn't rewrite in config.php

Tags: php, opencart, hosting

I want to make url modification after install opencart in to hosting during trial periond.I have read article https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9664/2182/how-to-change-opencart-url/ and make everything same re name url to my original domain name instead of assighned trial url and after upload to hostind config.php files was modified back to trial url what I was nominated before.I guess after modification config.php I need to run some command to make changes permanent.
If anyone knows solution prease respond.

root config file:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://uqsuscom.s56.yourdomain.com.ua/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://uqsuscom.s56.yourdomain.com.ua/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/storage/upload/');

// DB
```

admin config file:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://uqsuscom.s56.yourdomain.com.ua/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://uqsuscom.s56.yourdomain.com.ua/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://uqsuscom.s56.yourdomain.com.ua/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://uqsuscom.s56.yourdomain.com.ua/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/catalog/');
define('DIR_PUBLIC', '/sata1/home/users/uqsus/www/www.uqsus.com/');
```

Comment: The opencart URL is broken. 
Please specify exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Fixed url allready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After submitting technical issue to hosting support they fix me that problem.Horayy!